# Uniform correlated sampling in python

Tags: python, grid, correlation, sampling

Using Python 3 I am trying to sample 3 numbers that are related, each sample must sum up to 1.0

I am trying to take many samples and generate a list of correlated samples.

I am able to do this with random samples

```
all_fractions  = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=10) 
factions_a = [row[0] for row in all_fractions]
factions_b = [row[1] for row in all_fractions]
factions_c = [row[2] for row in all_fractions]
```

This produces three lists each containing correlated samples, but they are random and I would like them to be uniformly spaced on a grid.

Ideally the grid resolution would be controllable.

Thanks in advance for any help